# Compare tables on 2 db sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server with 2 databases.

I want to compare them and see which tables are on the first database and not on the second database.

Only the names of tables matter, I don't care about the values in those tables.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Tables in `db1` that don't exist in `db2`:

```
SELECT name FROM db1.sys.tables
EXCEPT
SELECT name FROM db2.sys.tables
ORDER BY name;
```

For more elaborate comparisons (like columns, indexes, and data types), don't re-invent the wheel, as [there are already tools that solve this problem](https://www.sentryone.com/products/pragmatic-workbench/dba-xpress/sql-development-monitoring-tools).* For more info on this in general, see [this blog post from ages ago](https://thebertrandfamily.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/).

*Disclaimer: I work for SentryOne.*

Answer (score 1):

When I check differences between 2 tables I usually use the `EXCEPT` clause.

so you could use below to see all the differences.

```
--Rows in DB1 which are absent from DB2
select * from DATABASE1.dbo.Table1
except
select * from DATABASE2.dbo.Table1

--Rows in DB2 which are absent from DB1
select * from DATABASE2.dbo.Table1
except
select * from DATABASE1.dbo.Table1
```

**Updated:**

Try below SQL for comparing two different databases:

```
SELECT T.[name] AS [table_name], AC.[name] AS [column_name],  TY.[name] AS 
   system_data_type FROM    ***Database Name 1***.sys.[tables] AS T  
   INNER JOIN ***Database Name 1***.sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id]      
   INNER JOIN ***Database Name 1***.sys.[types] TY ON AC.[system_type_id] = TY.[system_type_id] 
   EXCEPT SELECT T.[name] AS [table_name], AC.[name] AS [column_name], TY.[name] AS system_data_type FROM    ***Database Name 2***.sys.[tables] AS T  
   INNER JOIN ***Database Name 2***.sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id]  
   INNER JOIN ***Database Name 2***.sys.[types] TY ON AC.[system_type_id] = TY.[system_type_id]
```

Comment: The OP wants to find tables in one database that don't exist in the other, not rows that are in one table and not the other.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks. Updated my answer for comparing tables in DB (with columns and datatypes)